# Using yo angular-fullstack:openshift gives error 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname'

Tags: angularjs, git, ssh, openshift

Okay so I'm using `Openshift` to host my projects, and I just made a new account there yesterday. Yesterday I also used the command `yo angular-fullstack:openshift` in my `git-bash´ console to make an application there and to push my project to it. Worked fine.

Then I deleted the application on `Openshift` and today I want to upload it again. I run the same procedure and the same command. However now I get an error telling me that the hostname doesn't exist. Is this something which I can fix or is it one of those "try again later" problems?

**The Error**

```
Uploading your initial application code.
This may take several minutes depending on your connection speed...
 × ssh: Could not resolve hostname unityacademy-academiaunitate.rhcloud.com: no address associated with name

 × fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your 'dist' folder and redo a `grunt build` to generate a new 'dist' folder. This will ensure that your 'dist' folder is clean and not interfering with the creation process of you app. Make sure the old app on `OpenShift` is deleted and do the `yo angular-fullstack:openshift` command again.

This should do the trick.